# Limit memory usage of Yarn Build

Tags: frontend, yarnpkg

I am using yarn build in build pipeline, unfortunately of the build agent memory limitation
yarn build is clocking 7GB memory consumption and stays flat for a while as a result sometimes build agent gets disconnected and resulting in frequent build failures.

Is there any way by which we can limit the memory consumption of Yarn using some flags ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the **`NODE_OPTIONS`** environment variable to set the **`max_old_space_size`** globally to fix the issue.

For example:

```bash
# Set max_old_space_size to 7 GB.
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=7168
```

---

For [Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#hardware), each machine will have 7 GB of RAM and 14 GB of SSD disk space. However, since there are many pre-installed tools on the machine, the actually available disk space will be less.

It is guaranteed 10 GB of available disk space for pipeline to run, but in general you should never rely on having more than 10GB of disk space available.

---

If the actual space required by the '**`yarn build`**' process exceeds the ability of Microsoft-hosted agents, it is recommended using [self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#install) to run the build job.

Since the self-hosted agents normally are installed on the local machines (or VM) owned by yourself, you can control the Hardware on the machines to provide more available space for pipelines to run.

---